# Problems with iOS and input fields

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, input

I'm currently having an odd problem with a website but only with iOS devices, I have only tested this on the iPhone 5S as that is all I can get ahold of.

The problem is that when I click on an input field to enter a value the whole page shifts around, I've tried this page on Android and it works fine, the page stays the same, but on the iPhone the whole page shifts.

I have tried all the fixes that I have seen such as setting the font size on the input to 16px, and messing with the meta tag but I can't get anything to work.

Does any one have any ideas?

Forgot to put any code or a link, the website is [here](http://www.mywifi.solutions) however you'd need to go to this [page](http://www.mywifi.solutions/dev.php) to get a cookie to allow you to see the development site

And the inputs in question are at the bottom section, you have to swipe left until you get to the form

Thanks

Comment: nobody will be able to help you out unless you provide html and css code for the query in question.

Comment: Thanks for you response, it's a lot of code to attach to the question, it might be best if I just give you the link, the website is [link](http://www.mywifi.solutions) but in order to access the current site that's in development stage you'll need to go to this link first to get at cookie that will let you see the dev stuff [link](http://www.mywifi.solutions/dev.php)